# Sharepoint source and OLE DB destination .. data filtering

Tags: sharepoint, ssis, oledb

I pulled data from sharepoint to sql database through SSIS package

I need to schedule this for every 10 minutes everything is good

Every time i run package.we are having duplicate records

***I need to pull only updated and new items only to sql***

I have applied composit primary key option at destination its not working

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing much about the details of what you are doing, two things come to mind.

- Put constraints on your database so that duplicates aren't allowed.
  Better a foreign key violation or constraint error than duplicate
  data arriving.
- If you are utilizing an execute sql task, try using a merge
  statement.

Comment: thanks for the revert ... :)   these are not working ...!!

Comment: @Anil, constraints are not working or a MERGE statement with an execute sql task is not working?

Comment: constraints  are working first time pull ... not working from second time ..!!

Comment: @Anil, post the error message you are seeing and the SQL.